# Cmake can't find ITKconfig.cmake

Tags: c++, image-processing, cmake, vtk, itk

I'm trying to make a new project using ITK and VTK. I've created a new directory with the src and bin sub directories and created the Cmakelists.txt and .cxx files accordingly to ITK own guide intructions. However, when i try to configure using cMake, i get this warning stating that the file ITKconfig.cmake could not be found even though i have it on the path i added manually as you can see on the image.

[CMAKE warning and file path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qogp6.png)

What am i doing wrong here? Really want to start working on my project but i need to have it created first. Thanks in advance

Comment: The warning message you got tells about `ITK_DIR` variable. But you set `ITK` one...

Comment: I tried changing the ITK_DIR to the same path but when i do so, it gives me an error stating that it could not find load file.

Comment: So it will be the next problem. Actually, I found strange that "Config" file is located under `CMakeFiles` directory: normally, here are *intermediate* files. If you think this "Config" describes your VTK *installation*, then you definitely do something wrong - you need file under *installation prefix*, not under build directory. It could be that given "Config" file describes build directory of VTK, but again, I found this location being strange.

Comment: Some basic background how CMake tries to find libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41909627/2799037. You have to ammend the paths to VTK and ITK to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should set `ITK_DIR` to `C:/itk/bin` (judging by how you organize source and build folders).

Comment: I have ITKConfig.cmake in 3 locations: `C:\Dev\ITK-2017\ITKConfig.cmake`, `C:\Dev\ITK-2017\CMakeFiles\ITKConfig.cmake` and `C:\Dev\ITK-2017\CMakeTmp\ITKConfig.cmake`. And I point `ITK_DIR` to `C:/Dev/ITK-2017`.